# Unicode characters not appearing correctly in subprocess output

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, subprocess

I'm writing a python script for i3blocks to display the current artist and song on Spotify, and using `subprocess.run()` with playerctl to get the song data. The output doesn't display japanese characters correctly, and instead shows text like this `\xe9\xa3\x9b\xe3\x81\xb9`.  Newlines are also displayed as `\n` instead of an actual newline.

I've tried using string.decode("utf-8"), and got the error `'str' object has no attribute 'decode'`, and I tried `string.encode("utf-8")` and `string.encode("ascii")` before the decode, but the output was the same as without `string.decode()`.

```
output = str(subprocess.run(["playerctl", "metadata"], capture_output = True))
lines = output.split("\\n")
artist = lines[5].split("artist")[1].strip()
title = lines[8].split("title")[1].strip()
print(artist, title)
```

The correct output from this should be `tricot 飛べ`, but the actual output is `tricot \xe9\xa3\x9b\xe3\x81\xb9`

Answer (score 0):

This work

```
t = b"tricot \xe9\xa3\x9b\xe3\x81\xb9"
t.decode("utf-8")
```

Because your string must be - binary string for execute decode method

Comment: That works for literals.  Is there a way to convert the variables to a binary string and decode them?  The only way I know is with t.encode("utf-8"), but then the output of decode is the same as before.